# Live Chat button not showing agent status

Tags: liveagent, chat, livechattranscript

I have a standard Live Chat setup, but for whatever reason the button does not show the agent status. It keep showing that agents are offline.

This is what I have done so far:

My user has the "Chat User" checkbox checked. 
The button is setup ok, the routing is done by Omni-Channel Queues, I am assigned to the Queue.
ChatTranscript was added as a object to the right queue.
The Channel was added to the presence status. I have access to that presence status.
The Embedded Service Deployment is active - I've tested and activated offline support, and the offline window appeared. '
I've added the code on to a blank visualforce.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added users/profiles to the presence configurations?  has the routing configuration has been assigned to the queue?

Comment: Routing configuration was added to the queue. The profile was added to the presence configuration.

Comment: I have the very same problem. Have you solved your problem? If so, could you please provide an answer?

Comment: ok, in my case I have two different communities and I have configured the wrong community in the website URL